# VBA for deleting rows of first duplicates among many duplicates

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates

I am looking to write a VBA with the following steps:

1. Copy data from SheetA into SheetB
2. Deleting rows in SheetB using a reference column in SheetC
3. Sorting SheetB
4. Deleting rows of only first duplicates among many duplicates

I have succeeded from steps 1-3. However when I run the code for Step4, one of the values with duplicate was not deleted. This value populated a cell somewhere in the middle of the data.

However, when I run the same formula referencing only the value having errors as mentioned above, the code works fine.

Appreciate any assistance :)

Below is the VBA that I used:

```
Sub ProcessDataAndRemoveDuplicates()
    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    Dim dataSheet As Worksheet
    Dim masterList As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim currentVal As Variant
    Dim dictDuplicates As Object
    Set dictDuplicates = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    
    ' Set the reference to the target sheet
    Set targetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Total Renom") ' Change to the actual name of the target sheet
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Set the reference to the data sheet
    Set dataSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Active Sheet")
    Set masterList = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Free Renom").Range("C:C") ' Change to the actual range in Free Renom
    
    ' Copy and paste values from "Total Renom" to "Active Sheet"
    targetSheet.UsedRange.Copy
    dataSheet.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    
    ' Delete rows where corresponding value in column P appears in the list
    lastRow = dataSheet.Cells(dataSheet.Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = lastRow To 2 Step -1
        valueToCheck = dataSheet.Cells(i, "P").Value ' Assuming column P is 16
        
        If valueToCheck <> "" And Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(masterList, valueToCheck) > 0 Then
            dataSheet.Rows(i).Delete
        End If
    Next i
    
    ' Sort the ActiveSheet by column P and then by column N
    With dataSheet.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("P:P"), Order:=xlAscending
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("N:N"), Order:=xlAscending
        .SetRange Range("A:R") ' Change the range to match your data
        .Header = xlYes
        .Apply
    End With
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True ' Ensure screen updating is turned on to see the debug output
    Debug.Print "Debug Output - Start of Duplicate Removal Loop"
    
    ' Delete the first instance of duplicates based on column P
    lastRow = dataSheet.Cells(dataSheet.Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To lastRow
    currentVal = dataSheet.Cells(i, "P").Value
    
        If currentVal <> "" Then
         If Not dictDuplicates.Exists(currentVal) Then
            dictDuplicates.Add currentVal, i
         Else
            dataSheet.Rows(dictDuplicates(currentVal)).Delete
            dictDuplicates(currentVal) = i
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    
    Application.CutCopyMode = False ' Clear the clipboard
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    ' Return to the top of the sheet
    dataSheet.Activate
    dataSheet.Cells(1, 1).Select
    
    MsgBox "Done! Data processed, duplicates removed, and returned to the top.", vbInformation
End Sub
```

Comment: With this technic after founding an identical value and delete the first line your loop will skip a line from testing because delete moves all rows up while you increment the loop counter.

Comment: If you have five (1,2,3,4,5) rows with same value which rows you want to delete?

Comment: @Blackcat meaning to say it makes more sense to reference from the back than the front?
if 5 rows with same value, to delete row 1 only and keep the rest

Comment: Exactly you don't have to care of the "renumbering" of the rows.

Comment: Are the same P-values still together after sorting on N however? If they're not, you'll have an issue when comparing with the previous row's P-value. I mean: when will you know it's the actual first occurrence of the P-value when going backwards if they're not together?

Comment: Yup they remain together. However, is there a way to foolproof it? @Notus_Panda

Comment: If you're checking on P-Value, to be sure, you'd sort on N first, then on P. Deleting row 1 of 5 identical values deletes the first occurrence btw, not the first duplicate so if that's still what you want, then Black Cat's answer looks like your fit.

Answer (score 1):

This checks the previous row content and if different and duplicated then delete first row of identical values.

```
For i = LastRow To 2 Step -1
    currentval = datasheet.Cells(i, "P").value
    
        If currentval <> "" Then
         If Not dictduplicates.Exists(currentval) Then
            dictduplicates.Add currentval, i
         ElseIf datasheet.Cells(i - 1, "P").value <> currentval Then
         datasheet.Rows(i).Delete
            'dictduplicates(currentval) = i
         End If
        End If
    Next i
```